# Prevent attack with HttpServletRequest getServerName and getRequestURL

Tags: java, security

We understand that these two methods from HttpServletRequest which is getServerName and getRequestURL can bee spoofed by modifying host header in browser.

One solution is to get whitelist of all domains/serverNames and validate against it. Is there any alternative solutions to this when we need server name or domain from which request is coming from?

Comment: basically don't trust it/don't use it for anything important - Aside from that, you might be able to do something with programs like nginx.

Comment: Nearly every security step you might consider has a way (or _many_ ways) for bad actors to work around it. What are you actually solvihng for?